# How quickly can lasers of various wavelengths and powers impair human vision or cause pain in the eyes?

Tags: human-biology, human-eye

There is a discussion on HackerNews about how self-driving cars might be susceptible to confusion attacks using a cheap laser pointer and a RaspberryPi.

Some people argue that human drivers, too, are susceptible to attacks by laser pointers.

For lasers in the visible spectrum, I'm pretty sure that the human driver can tell he/she is under attack very quickly. But how about lasers outside the visible spectrum? Since you can't see the laser, the only way you can tell something is wrong is if your vision is impaired or you feel pain in your eyes. How quickly can that happen?